# Having problems reading .STL file in 10-myfirst.urdf

Tags: urdf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to the urdf tutorials. I am trying to load an STL file using 01-myfirst.urdf.

De urdf file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="myfirst">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://urdf/Part1.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot>
```

The file Part1.str is in the urdf folder within the package.

The command I am using in the root of the package:

```
~/moveit_ws/src/urdf_tutorial$ roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
```

This is the message I am getting is:

```
[ERROR] [1579020199.142407500]: Could not load resource [package://urdf/Part1.stl]: Unable to open file "package://urdf/Part1.stl".
```

Part1.stl is an ascii file. On the suggestion on someone else's post I underst I needed to remove the SOLID statement in the file. But to me the system cannot find the Part1.stl file at all.

What am I doing wrong? All help will be appreciated
Regards
Nico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341719/having-problems-reading-.stl-file-in-10-myfirst.urdf/) by [nico verduin](https://answers.ros.org/users/50901/nico-verduin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to specify the package as well. The filename format is `package://PACKAGENAME/PATHTOFILE`, so in this case, I'm guessing it would be `package://urdf_tutorial/urdf/Part1.stl`

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2020-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nico verduin](https://answers.ros.org/users/50901/nico-verduin/) on 2020-01-14**:
Great!!!!! That was the solution. Have to get used to the notation
Thanks
Nico